# Add Node to D3 Tree v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I am using D3 v4 to build a tree.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a6pLqpxw/

I am now trying to add support for dynamically adding (and removing) children from a selected node.

However I cannot get the chart to redraw without having to perform a complete redraw. I have modified the code from the collapsible tree diagram code at: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd

Specifically the following block does not perform a recalculation of the layout for its children.

```
document.getElementById('add-child').onclick = function() {
  console.log(selected);
  selected.children.push({
    type: 'resource-delete',
    name: new Date().getTime(),
    attributes: [],
    children: []
  });

  update(selected);
};
```

Does anyone have any good examples of dynamically adding/removing nodes to tree's in D3.js v4?

Answer (score 24):

I came up with this solution for **Adding new Node dynamically to D3 Tree v4.** .

D3 v4 tree requires Nodes.

Create Nodes from your tree data (json) using `d3.hierarchy(..)` and pushed it into it's `parent.children` array and update the tree.

**Code Snippet**

```
//Adding a new node (as a child) to selected Node (code snippet)
var newNode = {
    type: 'node-type',
    name: new Date().getTime(),
    children: []
  };
  //Creates a Node from newNode object using d3.hierarchy(.)
  var newNode = d3.hierarchy(newNode);

  //later added some properties to Node like child,parent,depth
  newNode.depth = selected.depth + 1; 
  newNode.height = selected.height - 1;
  newNode.parent = selected; 
  newNode.id = Date.now();

  //Selected is a node, to which we are adding the new node as a child
  //If no child array, create an empty array
  if(!selected.children){
    selected.children = [];
    selected.data.children = [];
  }

  //Push it to parent.children array  
  selected.children.push(newNode);
  selected.data.children.push(newNode.data);

  //Update tree
  update(selected);
```

---

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a6pLqpxw/8/)

---

```js
// ### DATA MODEL START

var data = {
 type: 'action',
  name: '1',
  attributes: [],
  children: [{
   type: 'children',
   name: '2',
    attributes: [{
     'source-type-property-value': 'streetlight'
    }],
    children: [{
     type: 'parents',
    name: '3',
      attributes: [{
       'source-type-property-value': 'cable'
      }],
      children: [{
       type: 'resource-delete',
     name: '4',
        attributes: [],
        children: []
      }]
    }, {
     type: 'children',
    name: '5',
      attributes: [{
       'source-type-property-value': 'lantern'
      }],
      children: []
    }]
  }]
};

// ### DATA MODEL END

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
 width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").
 append("svg").
  attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left).
  attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).
  append("g").
  attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0, duration = 750, root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(data, function(d) {
 return d.children;
});
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

var selected = null;

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
   links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
   d.y = d.depth * 180
  });

  // ### LINKS

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('line.link').
   data(links, function(d) {
     return d.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().
   append('line').
    attr("class", "link").
    attr("stroke-width", 2).
    attr("stroke", 'black').
    attr('x1', function(d) {
     return source.y0;
    }).
    attr('y1', function(d) {
     return source.x0;
    }).
    attr('x2', function(d) {
     return source.y0;
    }).
    attr('y2', function(d) {
     return source.x0;
    });
    
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);
  
  linkUpdate.transition().
   duration(duration).
    attr('x1', function(d) {
     return d.parent.y;
    }).
    attr('y1', function(d) {
     return d.parent.x;
    }).
    attr('x2', function(d) {
     return d.y;
    }).
    attr('y2', function(d) {
     return d.x;
    });

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition().
   duration(duration).
    attr('x1', function(d) {
     return d.parent.y;
    }).
    attr('y1', function(d) {
     return d.parent.x;
    }).
    attr('x2', function(d) {
     return d.y;
    }).
    attr('y2', function(d) {
     return d.x;
    });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().
   transition().
    duration(duration).
    attr('x1', function(d) {
     return source.x;
    }).
    attr('y1', function(d) {
     return source.y;
    }).
    attr('x2', function(d) {
     return source.x;
    }).
    attr('y2', function(d) {
     return source.y;
    }).
    remove();

 // ### CIRCLES

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
   .data(nodes, function(d) {
     return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().
    append('g').
    attr('class', 'node').
    attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    }).
    on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle').
   attr('class', 'node').
    attr('r', 25).
    style("fill", function(d) {
     return "#0e4677";
    });

  // Update
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition().
   duration(duration).
    attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
   });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node').
   attr('r', 25).
    style("fill", function(d) {
     return "#0e4677";
   }).
    attr('cursor', 'pointer');

  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().
   transition().
    duration(duration).
    attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    }).
    remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle').attr('r', 0);
  
  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    selected = d;
    document.getElementById('add-child').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('remove').disabled = false;
    update(d);
  }
}

document.getElementById('add-child').onclick = function() {
  
  //creates New OBJECT
  var newNodeObj = {
   type: 'resource-delete',
    name: new Date().getTime(),
    attributes: [],
    children: []
  };
  //Creates new Node 
  var newNode = d3.hierarchy(newNodeObj);
  newNode.depth = selected.depth + 1; 
  newNode.height = selected.height - 1;
  newNode.parent = selected; 
  newNode.id = Date.now();
  
  if(!selected.children){
    selected.children = [];
       selected.data.children = [];
  }
  selected.children.push(newNode);
  selected.data.children.push(newNode.data);
  
  update(selected);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-child" disabled="disabled">Add Child</button>
```

Comment: Very nice. You can save the lines `children: []` and `newNode.height = ...` since `d3.hiearchy` sets adequate values for those.

Answer (score 1):

The `height` calculation in the accepted answer fails to update the ancestors of the created node. This means, for example, that the `height` of the root will never increase, even as many children are added.

The following code fixes these problems:

```
function insert(par, data) {
   let newNode = d3.hierarchy(data);
   newNode.depth = par.depth + 1;
   newNode.parent = par;
   // Walk up the tree, updating the heights of ancestors as needed.
   for(let height = 1, anc = par; anc != null; height++, anc=anc.parent) {
     anc.height = Math.max(anc.height, height);
   }
   if (!par.data.children) {
      par.children = [];
      par.data.children = [];
   }
   par.children.push(newNode);
   par.data.children.push(newNode.data);
}
```

It should be noted that the `d3.tree` layout algorithm doesn't actually use the `height` parameter, which is probably why it wasn't noted before.

If we take this route of "minimum code that makes the code work", we can also get rid of the `par.data` update and just use:

```
function insert(par, data) {
   let newNode = d3.hierarchy(data);
   newNode.depth = par.depth + 1;
   newNode.parent = par;
   if (!par.children)
      par.children = [];
   par.children.push(newNode);
}
```

To be functionally equivalent to the previous answer, we would write:

```
insert(selected, {
   type: 'node-type',
   name: new Date().getTime()
});
update(selected);
```